# FIND method doesn't exist in pymongo nor VERSION?

Tags: python, pymongo

I am trying to do some simple stuff with my pymongo with a staging database. so the first thing as usual

```
import pymongo
connection = pymongo.Connection(host = 'mongodb://username:password@alaki-staging.member0.mongolayer.com:37017,/dbname?safe=true&slaveOk=true&fsync=true&journal=true&ssl=true')
```

and now just

```
connection.find({})
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MypythonCode\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    connection.find({})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 769, in __call_
_
    self.__name, self.__connection.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'find' me
thod on a 'Connection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

C:\Python27>python.exe D:\MypythonCode\test.py > test.d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MypythonCode\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    connection.find({})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 769, in __call_
_
    self.__name, self.__connection.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'find' me
thod on a 'Connection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

or even to check the version !?

```
connection.version()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    connection.version()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 769, in __call_
_
    self.__name, self.__connection.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'version'
 method on a 'Connection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

any suggestion ?!

Comment: -1 for not thinking. You are calling find() on the connection object and not a collection. Why should the connection implement find()? find() is functionality of collections. Please RTFM

Comment: you were damn right ! I was querying on the connection ! feel free to remove the question !